Pd pivot table lambda function to join column values with exceptions not working
I am currently working with a dataframe looking at Kentucky oil wells with pandas and want to create a pivot table using an API identifier. Since ther are various duplicates, I also wanted to join non unique values.
Below is an example of the dataframe:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'API': ['16101030580000', '16101030580000', '16129057600000','16013006300000'], 
                   'Date': ['0000/00/00','6/15/2007', '5/25/2020', '7/31/2014'],
                   'Annual_Oil':[300,'nan',150, 360],
                   'State':['KY','None', 'None', 'KY']})

Additionally, I created a list of values that I did not want to join. However, when runnning the code, I get some values in the dataframe that should not be there.
list_none = ['none', 'nan', 'NAN','None', '0000/00/00','000']
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'API',
                        aggfunc = lambda x: (','.join(x.unique().astype(str)) if x not in list_none else x),
                        sort = False)

The output for this example dataframe looks like
                Date                    Annual_Oil State
API         
16101030580000  0000/00/00,6/15/2007    300,nan    KY,None
16129057600000  5/25/2020               150        None
16013006300000  7/31/2014               360        KY

Is there a way to restructure the lambda function within the pivot table or would I have to get rid of the unwanted joins manually?

Please provide code for a [mre] of df

@mozway thank you for that, I just uploaded a sample of the dataframe

You should filter the values within the join:
list_none = ['none', 'nan', 'NAN', 'None', '0000/00/00', '000']
df1 = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index='API',
    aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(
        i for i in x.unique().astype(str) if i not in list_none
    ),
    sort=False,
)

Alternative using a custom function:
def cust_join(x):
    x = x.dropna().astype(str)
    return ','.join(x[~x.isin(list_none)].unique())

df1 = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index='API',
    aggfunc=cust_join,
    sort=False,
)

Output:
                     Date Annual_Oil State
API                                       
16101030580000  6/15/2007        300    KY
16129057600000  5/25/2020        150      
16013006300000  7/31/2014        360    KY


thank you for this, it's really helpful. I have a question though; is there a way to fix the code so that it will also leave the value if it stands alone? I noticed that it also got rid of None found in state even though there was nothing joined to it.

You convert to string and explicitly remove 'None'. I'm not sure what you would expect

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'API': ['16101030580000', '16101030580000', '16129057600000','16013006300000'], 
                   'Date': ['0000/00/00','6/15/2007', '5/25/2020', '7/31/2014'],
                   'Oil':[300,'nan',150, 360],
                   'State':['KY','None', 'None', 'KY']})
print(df)
'''
              API        Date        Oil State
0  16101030580000  0000/00/00        300    KY
1  16101030580000   6/15/2007        nan  None
2  16129057600000   5/25/2020        150  None
3  16013006300000   7/31/2014        360    KY
'''

# List of values to exclude
list_none = ['none', 'nan', 'NAN', 'None', '0000/00/00', '000']

res = df.pivot_table(
df, index ='API',aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(
    x[x.astype(str).str.lower().isin(list_none) == False ].unique().astype(str)
)#join    
)
print(res)
'''
                     Date  Oil State
API                                 
16013006300000  7/31/2014  360    KY
16101030580000  6/15/2007  300    KY
16129057600000  5/25/2020  150      
'''

